# How do I add debug info to assembler output

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction

I am writing compilers (for toy languages at first, later for industrial-strength languages) and wish to add debugging information to the assembler output (currently Sparc assembler).  Are there any source examples, even of toy compilers, to learn about this short of reading GCC or LLVM?

Comment: I asked the wrong question, now corrected.  Apologies.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources, whether something to read or toy compilers, is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of debugging information.

The spec. of the "dwarf" debugging information that is used by most commercial development software is found on http://dwarfstd.org/.

Linux mainly uses the "stabs" debugging information defined by some GNU freeware which is documented at http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/stabs.html. "Stabs" seems to be easier to be implemented.

There are some other types of debugging information (COFF, Watcom, Microsoft, ...) that are often processor or OS dependent.

Oracle (if you use Solaris on Sparc) uses the "Dwarf" format, Linux uses the "Stabs" format by default but "Dwarf" is also supported under Linux. Most microcontroller development tools also use "Dwarf".

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I asked the wrong question (supra).  Professional compiler writers have told me to start with stabs (still accepted on Solaris by gdb and adb) before trying dwarf but none had any simple tutorials to point to.